# generically finite morphism of degree $d$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the definition of a generically finite morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of degree $d$?

And if f it generically finite of degree 1 is f birational? Under which conditions is $f$ surjective?

Comment: if $X$ and $Y$ are integral and $f$ dominant, then that the morphism on the generic stalks is an extension of degree d. Which should also answer the rest of your questions.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean with morphism on the generic stalks is an extension of degree $d$? I'm sorry but I don't know a lot about it.

Comment: If the schemes are integral, then the stalks at the generic points are fields (the field of function of the scheme), if the morphism is dominant, it means that it send the generic point to the generic point, you get therefore a morphism $O_{Y, \xi_Y} \to O_{X, \xi_X}$ which are fields, I just mean that this a field extension of degree $d$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand it now. But can I only define generically finite morphisms of degree d for integral $X$ and $Y$? (So the only irreducible components are $X$ and $Y$ themselves

Comment: Well you can still extend a little bit the defintion by looking at irreducible compoents of $X$ as long as they dominate $Y$, but usually this is the case yes.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: If $f$ is of degree 1 than it must be birational but is $f$ also surjective? With surjective I mean that the underlying topological spaces are surjective.

Comment: Well, no but if you assume that the varieties are proper for instance it will be.

Comment: Isn't it enough to assume that only $X$ is proper?

Comment: If $Y$ is separated over the base field yes.